# How to perform daily backups?

Tags: macos, mac, backup, svn, session

While developing an iPhone project, I create new folders on each day and as follows

```
* November 2009
      o 01-DEC-2009
            + MyProject
      o 02-DEC-2009
            + MyProject
* December 2009
```

I make backups of my project daily, I know this isn't a proper way of making backups.  I want to know what is the proper solution for this?

I am on Mac OS X & it is connected to a Windows server.  Is it possible to make backups on Windows svn server?  Is there an alternate option available within Mac OSX?

I cannot attach anything to the PC via USB, so, Time Machine isn't preferable for this specific requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are developing software, rather than manual backups and snapshots, you should start using [source control software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control), like [Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) (which you mention but clearly have no idea how it works) or [git](http://progit.org/book/) (slightly more difficult to learn but gives you more power in the long run). Since you have a svn server running on windows I would try learning using it first.

Having said that, if you really have to use manual backups, first note that Xcode provides a snapshot feature, which may be enough for you. Still, if you don't trust Xcode, one solution would be to use something similar in spirit to time machine, where you have a full copy of any directory plus differential backups for a specific amount of time. [rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/) would fit this very well (I've used it to back windows network shares).

[rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/) can be obtained either as source code or you can also install it  prepackaged binaries through systems like [Mac ports](http://www.macports.org/).

Comment: strongly recommend thread starter read about subversion/mercurial/git and use it.

Answer (score 3):

Time Machine will make daily backups to a local external hard drive, or network-attached Time Capsule. This is the absolute easiest solution if you aren't concerned about the backups being off-site.

Comment: But I want solution out of time machine. I already know about time machine but I don't want to use it. Thank for the reply sir. U r right. But I am finding the other solution.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want Time Machine? It is completely automated, makes daily backups, and is built in to the operating system.

Comment: Oke. Let me explain the problem. time machine is finding apple device using through air port. I have only one mac in the office & have no other device.

Comment: You can use time machine with any external hard drive. You don't need an Airport base station. A regular USB hard drive from any vendor will work fine with TM.

Comment: Well, that is a rather important fact. You should update your original question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're set on avoiding time machine, and really want to use an ad-hoc script setup, you may want to check out [rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/).  I use a combination of rdiff-backup (fired off through [backupninja](https://labs.riseup.net/code/projects/show/backupninja/)) and [jungledisk](http://www.jungledisk.com/) to ensure that I have everything backed up.

This solution accomplishes the following:

1. Automatic
2. Versions everything, no worry about data loss.
3. Minimal file duplication -- optimal disk space use (but no compression).
4. Offsite backup.

If you want to go a bit more complicated and avoid the need to use a service like JungleDisk and just use a remote server, you may want to look at [Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/), which will encrypt the backups on the remote server too.

Comment: What options do you use for rdiff-backup so that it writes to a jungledisk mount point?

Comment: In this scenario JungleDisk is mounted as a drive. You could also hook something up using generic WebDav mounting system. As an aside, I ditched all of this and switched to CrashPlan. It's cheaper for all my data and just works across systems and multiple backup destinations, both local and remote.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not fear scripting, you could try tarsnap (needs to be built from source for OSX). You can either cron your backups, or push a "button" (script) when you decide a backup is needed. I wrote a bit about it at: 
https://caffeinatedcode.com/posts/online-backups-for-the-truly-paranoid/ "Online Backups for the Truly Paranoid"

Tarsnap is secure, easy to use, uses Amazon S3 (geo-replicated across the country), and inexpensive (but not free).

You do need to clarify for yourself the difference between revision control and backup. They are not necessarily the same, although many use their offsite versioning mechanism as their main backup tool. Your requirements might be satisfied simply by using svn on a hosting provider like Dreamhost.