# Lazy linux backup system?

Tags: linux, backup

Ok, so I want to say Time Machine, but that's note exactly what I'm looking for. I want to set up a system that will regularly (hourly?) back up the /home directory of our machine. time Machine style things are naturally preferable since they save space by only saving the changes, but honestly, this is important enough that I can suffer some waste.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use rsync, the crontab and some scripts to take regular snapshots.

http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/

there is also rdiff-backup, which does much the same thing:

http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/

and a third option is rsnapshot:

http://rsnapshot.org/

also, take a look at this very similar question:

[How to perform daily backups?](https://superuser.com/questions/82456/regular-backups)

Comment: Shoot, beat me to it!

Comment: I just use I set of rsync scripts at the moment, I keep meaning to move to one of the snapshot approaches.

Comment: I've also used Dirvish in the past--it's just another rsync-based snapshot script.